# The difference between char*s=new char[] and char s[20]?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<process.h>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class List{
    class Node{
    public:
        T num;
        Node*next;
    }*head,*tail;
public:
    List(){
        head = tail = NULL;
    }
    void insert(T *n){
        Node*tmp=new Node;
        tmp->next = head;
        tmp->num = *n;
        head = tmp;
        if (tail == NULL){
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }
    void append(T*n){
        Node*tmp=new Node;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        tmp->num = *n;
        if (tail == NULL){
            head = tail = tmp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }
    T Get(){
        if (head == NULL){
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            T t = head->num;
            Node*p = head;
            if (head->next == NULL){
                head = tail = NULL;
            }
            else{
                head = head->next;
            }
            delete (p);
            return t;
        }
    }
};
class person{
public:
    char*name=new char[];//problem lies here!
    //char name[20];
    int age;
    float hight;
    person(){}
};
int main(){
    person a;
    List<int>link1;
    List<person>link2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> a.name >> a.age >> a.hight;
        link2.insert(&a);
        link1.append(&i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        a = link2.Get();
        link2.append(&a);
        cout << a.name << " " << link1.Get() << endl;
    }
}
```

As the explanation goes in the code, when using `char*name=new char[]` to replace `char name[20]`, the program went wrong. It wouldn't output all the names as expected, but only print the last input name 5 times. So what's the difference between these two expressions?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't spam language tags. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: static allocation and heap allocation are different.

Comment: A question about `new` like this means you are programming in C++, not C; `new` is not an operator in C.  Please don't dual tag questions with C and C++ unless the question is really about the interactions between the two languages.

Comment: I don't think "static allocation" is a good term because it can live inside a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: People put in their CV like "Proficiency: C/C++" and most of them dont understand the difference.

Comment: `char s[20];` is not static allocation, it's automatic memory allocation. Let's stop using words we don't understand.

Comment: @neeKo but it doesn't work...

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I think it is more complicated than that. `char s[20];` can be static (e.g. global, static local), automatic (e.g. local), or dynamic (e.g. a class member, and then `new` the class).

Comment: Let's not quibble (troll) over words often used interchangeably [**Static memory allocation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation)

Comment: @NickyC It's not more complicated than that. All of those are mutually exclusive storage durations.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I am just saying this syntax may be used to do static allocation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The article you link exactly opposes your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`new char[]` doesn't compile under GCC. :) `new char[20]`, however, does.

`char[20]` tells the compiler that you want 20 characters in an array. This is typically allocated on your call stack. Very large allocations can cause stack overflows so this is discouraged in some circles.

If you use `new` you must call `delete[] name` or you will have a memory leak. If you call `delete name` you will have an error in your code because the array will not be deleted, only that one `char *`.

Comment: Did you mean `g++` ? `new char[20]` will not compile under gcc, but it will under `g++`

Comment: @sjsam No. GCC is the name of the actual compiler, `g++` is the C++ front-end.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper : I meant the binary, not the collection ;-) I see that \@sam has capitalized `GCC` and I think he actually meant the compiler collection itself. :-)

Comment: Correct. Thank you. :) I used /usr/bin/g++ and for kicks I ran clang++, just to be sure. :)